# CSS, Hover, position absolute and responsiveness error

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, hover

I want to position a div on top of another div. But i can't find a way to implement that without the use of position absolute. And position absolute makes my page non responsive. I want to achieve the effect as shown below.

These two are divs with images. The bottom translucent black color is the background with transition and z-index change.

I currently have just the two divs with image and background.

I have to add the button and font-size on hover using jquery or is there any better way to implement this ?

[image]

HTML :

```
<div class="col-sm-3 hvr-sweep-to-top">
    <img class="img-responsive " src="../images/thumbnailGridImage.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 hvr-sweep-to-top">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/thumbnailGridImage.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.hvr-sweep-to-top {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  top: 60%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-top:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-top:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-top:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-top:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

**THIS hvr-swipe-to-top is extracted from hover.css under MIT Liscense**

Comment: @Pete added the html and css

Answer (score 0):

I have made demo same as well as you need and don't worry about use of `position: absolute`.

***check it out : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Dynamic_Designer/5153bh0m/)***

If you will use `position: absolute` with parent use of `position: relative` then it will be fully Responsive design.



**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="hvr-sweep-to-top">
        <div class="img-box">
          <img src="http://kissinmaldives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cropped-maldives.jpg" alt="maldives" />
        </div>
        <div class="caption-box">
          <span class="caption-title">Maldives</span>
          <a class="btn call-to-action">Book a Trip</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="hvr-sweep-to-top">
        <div class="img-box">
          <img src="http://kissinmaldives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cropped-maldives.jpg" alt="maldives" />
        </div>
        <div class="caption-box">
          <span class="caption-title">Maldives</span>
          <a class="btn call-to-action">Book a Trip</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="hvr-sweep-to-top">
        <div class="img-box">
          <img src="http://kissinmaldives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cropped-maldives.jpg" alt="maldives" />
        </div>
        <div class="caption-box">
          <span class="caption-title">Maldives</span>
          <a class="btn call-to-action">Book a Trip</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="hvr-sweep-to-top">
        <div class="img-box">
          <img src="http://kissinmaldives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cropped-maldives.jpg" alt="maldives" />
        </div>
        <div class="caption-box">
          <span class="caption-title">Maldives</span>
          <a class="btn call-to-action">Book a Trip</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top .caption-box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top .caption-box span.caption-title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top .caption-box a.btn.call-to-action {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: none;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover .caption-box span.caption-title {
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover .caption-box a.call-to-action {
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: Now, you have to do just couple of things like replace your content instead of this dummy content, make your design pixel perfect according to your design spect file and add some transition on hover so it will be look more smoothly and attractive.